# Get data when multiple values exist in second table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to check if data both values are there in second table

user table:

```
id | firstname  | lastname
1  | John       | Doe
2  | Test       | User
```

user_custom_fields table:

```
id | field_value| name      | user_id
1  | male       | gender    | 1
2  | 20         | age       | 1
```

I want to get the user if both condition matches. if i pass `where user_custom_fields.gender=male and user_custom_fields.age = 20`, it should return user 1.

This is what i am trying

```
SELECT 
    users.*
FROM
    "users" AS "users"
    INNER JOIN "users_custom_fields" AS "users_custom_fields" ON "users"."id" = "users_custom_fields"."user_id" 
    AND ( "users_custom_fields"."field_value" = '20' AND "users_custom_fields"."field_value" = 'male' ) 
    AND "users_custom_fields"."custom_field_id" IN ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from user_customer_fields ucf
              where ucf.user_id = u.id and
                    ucf.id = 1 and
                    ucf.value = 'male'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from user_customer_fields ucf
              where ucf.user_id = u.id and
                    ucf.id = 2 and
                    ucf.value = '20'
             ) ;
```

You don't need `join` because you don't want to return the values.  If you did, you can use *two* joins:

```
select u.*
from users u join
     user_customer_fields ucfg
     on ucfg.user_id = u.id and
        ucfg.id = 1 and
        ucfg.value = 'male' join
     user_customer_fields ucfg
     on ucfg.user_id = u.id and
        ucfg.id = 2 and
        ucfg.value = '20';
```